# Root user is changing permission of a file after modification

Tags: linux, permissions

Before working on a file in my dev server, I am giving root:root and 777 permissions on that file.

But when I modify something as root user in that file, its permission is changing to 640 (-rw-r-----) ( so next time it becoming problem to execute that file).

It is not the case in my other machine.

Could you suggest what will be wrong on this server?

I am using "vi file.py" and then editing that file in RHEL6 server.

I am logging into this server with my user account and then doing "sudo su" to become the root user and then changing the permissions with 777, and then running "vi file.py" to modify that file.

Comment: Impossible to say w/ more info.  How (by which means) are you modifying the file? What filesystem type does it reside on? That said: `777` is usually a terrible mistake.

Comment: I am using "vi file.py" and then editing that file in RHEL6 server

Comment: And the file-system type? It's *not* normal for vim to modify permissions.

Comment: File system is xfs

Comment: Hmmm ... no, no idea for an explanation given the circumstances. If you don't have some sort of  automation or CI/CD going on try using RHEL's audit-daemon to find out what's going on.

Comment: sure thank you. As I am not the Linux admin, I am not able to provide the information that is helpful to debug.

I will try to do your suggestion, thank you for your help. I am sure that the "vi" command is changing permission after closing the file with ":wq!"